# increase cassandra performance for read/write operations

Tags: cassandra

I am using 4 cores and 8gb system and working on a single node with replication factor = 1. It is taking 3 mins to write approx 350k data to table. I want to increase the speed of read and write operation. I would want to explore as many options possible.

Comment: That's going to be hard to answer without seeing the table definition.  Can you edit your question to include it?

Comment: @SuyashRaj, could you please also add additional details about the version of Cassandra, the driver & its version, write consistency levels used, data model, etc., Have you already sized your cluster? I wanted to take a page from here, https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse-planning/doc/planning/planningTesting.html And there are tools like https://docs.nosqlbench.io and cassandra-stress that could help you with the cluster sizing exercise. Another thing to know is anti-patterns, https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse-planning/doc/planning/planningAntiPatterns.html

Comment: @Madhavan almost all of these are defaultly configured. Can you mention some concepts that will be helpful for increasing performnance or tools?

Comment: @SuyashRaj, the key to success is planing the size, data model, testing. Design your data models based on your queries/access patterns. Always, try to query by the full primary key without leveraging ALLOW FILTERING.. you could practice with https://www.datastax.com/learn/data-modeling-by-example also this planning guide https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse-planning/doc/ is key and I would assume most of these also applies to OSS C* as well. If you're still struck, you could hire C* consultants to help with your architecture/design/db goals/etc www.datastax.com/luna offer free trial too.Good luck!

Comment: You're very welcome @SuyashRaj and good luck with your successful planning & implementation